# How do I get rid of the vertical bar in the url

Tags: wp-title

I was wondering how to get rid from the vertical bar in the browser url, see image.

I thought it was wp_title and set it too false like: `<?php wp_title(false); ?>` but doesn't work.
How can I solve this?

Thnkx

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This will be in your header.php, something like:

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
```

Just change the vertical line to be included in the conditional, so that it shows on the other pages but not on the homepage, such as:

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?>| <?php } ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
```

Or customise it any way you like, such as page title only:

```
<title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
```

Comment: I have check it, but the first snippet I don't have the vertical bar hardcoded. Have tried your solutions, but it doesn't work for me. The vertical bar is show in all pages only the homepage not. Can it be from the SEO plugin you think? @Monkey

Comment: @Casper It's easy to check. Deactivate the plugin and take a look. Reactivate it if not.

Comment: Yes, it comes from the plugin. But don't know how to change that.

Comment: It should be in the plugin settings, depending on the plugin. If it's not, perhaps you can use another plugin. Yoast's SEO plugin is a good one. Look in Settings/Titles & Metas / Post Types - for the title templates.